# Check status of "File and Printer Sharing" with script

Tags: networking, script, automation, cmd.exe, windows-firewall

I am attempting to write scripts that test that status of important settings on my Windows 7 or Windows 10 PC's. Turning the "File And Printer Sharing" setting OFF/ON is well-documented. But is there a command or a registry key that would give me the Boolean status of the "File and Printer Sharing" for the different network types (public, private, domain)? I want to verify that "File and Printer Sharing" is turned off for public networks and turned on for private networks.

Comment: `net share` or `wmic path Win32_Share get/value` return basic facts; I'd guess that extended info depends on active firewall setting.